# Second execution follows href

Tags: javascript, jquery

With a list of products, and once a 'remove from wishlist' button is clicked, it then removes that product from said product list, along with an AJAX request to the back-end for it to be removed via SQL.

The first click works, the jQuery executes and the product is then removed. The second click on the same type of button for any product, then loads the href instead of executing the jQuery, it's meant to execute the jQuery.

I've tried calling it as a static function from the anchor onclick="return removeFromWishlist();"

Have also tried executing the jQuery on the anchor link click via the jQuery event instead of the button tag itself.

```
jQuery('.button-wishlist').on('click', function (index) {

    event.preventDefault();

    // Calls the AJAX to remove it from the back-end via SQL etc
    // The response is JSON within the following call
    removeProductAjax(this);

    console.log('removing product from the wishlist');

    // Get the cell position of the product to remove from the wishlist
    var position = jQuery(this).parent().parent().parent().data('cell');

    var html = [];
    var cells = 0;

    jQuery('.wishlist_container .col-md-4').each (function () {
        //
        if (jQuery(this).data('cell') == position) {
            cells++;
        }
        else if (jQuery(this).data('cell') !== undefined) {
            html.push(jQuery(this).html());
            cells++;
        }
    });

    var upto = 0;

    jQuery('.product-row').each (function () {
        var self = this;
        // Repopulate all the product lists excluding the one removed
        jQuery(self).children().each (function () {
            jQuery(this).html(html[upto]);
            upto++;
        });
    });

    // Then clear everything from upto and onwards!
    console.log('cells: ' + cells);
    console.log('upto: ' + upto);

    // let's change from array to 'standard' counting
    upto--;

    // Remove the last element!
    jQuery('.product-row').find('[data-cell=' + upto + ']').remove();

    // Check for any empty rows
    jQuery('.product-row').each (function () {
        if (jQuery(this).children().length == 0) {
            jQuery(this).remove();
        }
    });
});
```

The HTML is basically:

```
<div class="row product-row">
    <div class="row product-row"><div class="col-md-4" data-cell="0">
        <h1>product 1</h1>
        <a href="./page.php?page=cart&amp;unwish=660986" data-index="660986" class="wishlist-button" onclick="return removeProductFromWishlist(this);">
            <button name="wishlist" class="btn button-wishlist" data-type="remove">Remove from Wishlist</button>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4" data-cell="1">
        <h1>product 2</h1>
        <a href="./page.php?page=cart&amp;unwish=661086" data-index="661086" class="wishlist-button" onclick="return removeProductFromWishlist(this);">
            <button name="wishlist" class="btn button-wishlist" data-type="remove">Remove from Wishlist</button>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4" data-cell="2">
        <h1>product 3</h1>
        <a href="./page.php?page=cart&amp;unwish=661067" data-index="661067" class="wishlist-button" onclick="return removeProductFromWishlist(this);">
            <button name="wishlist" class="btn button-wishlist" data-type="remove">Remove from Wishlist</button>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm expecting it to execute the jQuery each time the "remove from wishlist" button is clicked, no matter what product, no matter what order. So, you can unwish many products, one after the other using AJAX / jQuery.

Comment: Try changing `jQuery('.button-wishlist').on('click', function (index)` to `jQuery(document).on('click', '.button-wishlist', function (event)`

Comment: The first argument of `.on('eventName', cb)`  callback is a jQuery `event` object - not an index. (as pointed by imtheman)

Comment: Never ever use `.parent().parent().parent().parent().parent()....` use simply https://api.jquery.com/closest/

Comment: Because you're removing and re-creating the buttons to the HTML when one of them is clicked, the new buttons don't have the same event handler registered to them. @imtheman's solution should work, because it attaches a single event handler to the document that checks what element was actually clicked.

Comment: Also, get used to set `type` attribute to button, otherwise will default to `type="submit"`. Instead you want it to be `type="button"`.

Comment: Also your `removeProductAjax` function should have a callback! `removeProductAjax(this, function(res) { /*was res successful? remove item from UI */ });` - By simply doing `removeProductAjax(this);` there's no guarantee that the item was actually removed from your database! (Or use Promises instead of "oldschool" callbacks)

Comment: Fantastic @imtheman thank you so much!
Also thanks for everyone's replies in general, very fast responses :D

Comment: Also, use the jQuery's `$` alias instead of losing your nails on the keyboard. Simply wrap your code into a DOM ready like `jQuery($=>{ /*Use $ alias here freely*/ });`

Comment: Also, don't use multiple `<h1>` in the same page. Use rather `<h2>` or others, or even `<header>` would be a better markup if you use `<article>` and `<section>` instead of the parent `<div>`s

Comment: Also, don't use inline JS - in specific cases could even raise an `unsafe-inline` flag. Instead use JS and `addEventListener` or jQuery `.on()`

Comment: Also, the Anchor `<a>` element, although it can wrap static context or block  elements like a `<div>`, it should **not contain** other action Elements like `<button>`. Don't do that.

Comment: Can you please explain that's all that fuss around `html = []` and the `var cells = 0;` , `upto++;`  etc? What's all that code supposed to do? I think you're overcomplicating your task...

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan thank you kindly for your advice, I'm implemented them now, it's good to hear your suggestions and tips for better practice.
In regards to over-complicating, yes, I tend to overthink, it's an issue. html variable stores all the div contents excluding the one removed, so I know which one's to render out replacing all the previous product div's. What would you suggest as more simplified method of doing this?
Thank you :)

Comment: @Gatty added an example. Just make sure to create a proper `removeProduct.php` file with the necessary code inside :)

Answer (score 1):

Follow all my comments under your Question...
And I think this is all the code you need.

PHP (I used i.e: `../removeProduct.php?id=`) should respond with some JSON like:

```
// PHP does here some DB deletions or fails.
// Send back to AJAX the deleted item ID (or null)
// and some (error?) message
echo json_encode(['id' => $id, 'message' => $message]);
exit;
// No more PHP here. We exit.
// jQuery will collect that JSON response as `res`
```

```js
jQuery(function($) {

  function removeProductAjax(id) {
    $.get("../removeProduct.php?id=" + id, 'json').always(function(res) {
    
      if (res.statusText === 'error') { // General error (path invalid or something...)
        return alert(`Error: Cannot remove product ID: ${id}`); // and exit function
      }
      
      if (!res.id) { // Something happened
        return alert(res.message); // Alert PHP's error message and exit function.
      }
      
      // All OK. Remove item from products
      $(".product-row").find(`[data-id="${res.id}"]`).remove();
    });
  }

  $('.product-row').on('click', '.product-remove', function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    removeProductAjax($(this).data('id'));
  });

});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<div class="row product-row">
  <div class="col-md-4" data-id="660986">
    <h3>product 1</h3>
    <button type="button" class="btn product-remove" data-id="660986">Remove from Wishlist</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4" data-id="661086">
    <h3>product 2</h3>
    <button type="button" class="btn product-remove" data-id="661086">Remove from Wishlist</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4" data-id="661067">
    <h3>product 3</h3>
    <button type="button" class="btn product-remove" data-id="661067">Remove from Wishlist</button>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```